# получить содержимое класса

Tags: c#

получаю структуру

```
DocumentList documents = Api.GetDocuments(authToken, box, 
    "AnyInvoiceDocumentType.Inbound", tobox, null, null, null, null, null, true, null);
```

Как я могу вывести содержимое?

```
logger.Debug("Except{0}", documents, null);
```

Отдает пустую строку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Структура данных [DocumentList](http://api-docs.diadoc.ru/ru/latest/proto/DocumentList.html) представляет собой список документов, возвращаемый методом `GetDocuments`. Поле `DocumentList.TotalCount` содержит общее количество документов, удовлетворяющих фильтру. Каждый элемент списка `DocumentList.Documents` представлен структурой [Document](http://api-docs.diadoc.ru/ru/latest/proto/Document.html).

Чтобы вывести документы таким образом, как пытаетесь Вы, то нужно сделать как-то так (если `logger.Debug` может принять одну строку `string`):

```
foreach(var document in documents)
    logger.Debug(string.Format("Except: {0}", document.FileName));
```

> `FileName` - имя файла документа, которое у него было при загрузке в
>   Диадок.

Перебрать все файлы в цикле [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx), а строку привести к нормальному формату через [метод String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). Необходимые ссылки прикреплены в ответе. Для ознакомления со структурой `Document` перейдите по ссылке: [Docs » Работа с документами » Document](http://api-docs.diadoc.ru/ru/latest/proto/Document.html).

Немного не понял, что вы имели в виду в этой строке:

```
logger.Debug("Except{0}", documents, null);
```

Поэтому оставил Ваш код `logger.Debug` с добавлением `String.Format`. Но, думаю, что будет полезна вот эта ссылка: [Способ трассировки и отладки в Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/815788). Или, можно вот так:

```
foreach(var document in documents)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Except: {0}", document.FileName));
```

Это если в у Вас можно писать в выходной поток. Ссылка: [Метод Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zdf6yhx5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Такое ощущение, что вы с программированием не знакомы.

[DocumentList](http://api-docs.diadoc.ru/ru/latest/proto/DocumentList.html)

Внутри листа есть свойство `Documents`, в котором коллекция структур `Document`.

[Document](http://api-docs.diadoc.ru/ru/latest/proto/Document.html)

А уже документы выводите как хотите и куда хотите.

Answer (score -1):

Для вывода коллекции в виде строки лучше применить сериализацию в удобочитаемый формат (например JSON), хотя в целом это не лучшее решение (отображать коллекцию в виде строки в логах)...

Про сериализацию:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm

А так примерно будет выглядеть лог:

```
logger.Debug($"Except{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(documents)}", null);
```